# I installed Ubuntu updates and wifi doesnt work anymore

Tags: wireless

I am working on a dell machine and wifi didnt work out of the box but I was able to get it to work. After doing updates the network appears in the place where you can edit connections but there is no way to connect.
When I first installed ubuntu I successfully tried this to get the wifi to work: [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers).
.
Today I updated my system using the software updater. Now when I click on the network indicator in the top panel it just shows `wired network disconnected` and no wireless networks at all, like it used to.
When I click edit connections I can find "A Network" but I cannot connect just edit it.
I did what was in the link again and still no wifi.
What do I do? Please be as specific as possible, I am new to ubuntu.

Edit -  I answered the post with 59^ and it is a Dell Latitude D620 and I am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS and nothing happens when I type those codes. I tried putting sudo in front of them also and still, nothing happened...

Comment: Could you please edit your post to include the following information: 1. What kind of Dell (notebook I am assuming?) are you using? 2. What ubuntu version are you using? 3. please open a terminal and post the outputs of `lspci | grep -i wireless` and `lsmod | grep bcm` ? and 4. please tell us which of the 38 answers provided in the question you linked did you follow? :P

Comment: I answered the post with 59^ and it is a Dell Latitude D620 and i am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS and give me a sec for the codes... um nothing happens when i type those codes. i tried putting sudo in front of them also and still, nothing happened...

Comment: apparently I assumed the wrong keywords when using grep. But no worries the info you posted on pastebin has all the relevant info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do:

```
sudo apt-get purge --remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe -rv wl
sudo modprobe -v b43
```

watch for error if any occur in the last two commands please continue.

Comment: It worked! I got an error on the -rv wl one but the wifi works now so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the terminal

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

this shuld solve the problem

if the above is not working this will fix the problem for sure

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

please let me know if it helped and what so i can edit the post thank you

Comment: i tried both and still - no wireless options.

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the contents of the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.  No internet then go to this link for running the script without internet.
<http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12350385>

Comment: did it here is the pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/D4QAxDVW

Comment: From the stuff you posted it seems like your system is blacklisting the required kernel modules in a different file than the fix you tried. You can try the following: Open a terminal and type `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf` and the put `#` in front of the following lines `blacklist b43, blacklist b43legacy, blacklist ssb, blacklist bcm43xx` and try to reboot

Comment: Still no wifi... D: my network appears under edit connections but there is no way to connect. But I did what you said Daniel and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: if anyone can come up with anything, I will be very happy. There has to be a reason the computer is doing this. Perhaps there is a way to uninstall the updates from earlier that created this mess?